# Cleanup space in windows 7

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reduce disk space used by Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/107360/reduce-disk-space-used-by-windows-7)

Hello,

Today I noticed that there is a lot of space that is eaten by windows folder in the folders winsxs(10 gb), installer (7.2 gb) assembly(2.6 gb).

Adobe (9.1 gb) in programfile(x86) and adobe(3.9 gb) in common folder and adobe (3.1 gb) in program files folder.

I was browsing for winsxs folder etc., and they seem to be important folders which should not be removed. I am running out of space on my laptop with these files majorly occupying the space. Which folders are unnecessary in adobe. This adobe is scattered all around the hard disk. 
Can someone suggest me the safe tool or folders that are safe to be removed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reduce disk space used by Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/107360/reduce-disk-space-used-by-windows-7) and [Possible to clean up some of the windows dir to free up drive space - windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/187703/possible-to-clean-up-some-of-the-windows-dir-to-free-up-drive-space-windows-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would reccomend installing a software like [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) which will scan your computer and remove unwanted files. This software doesn't take up much space when installed and also has a [portable version](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/builds) that does not require any installation; incase you do not want to loose any more space.

In addition to its standard cleaner options, also take time to look under the Tools > System Restore section of CCleaner. This option may let you remove some system files created from Restore points that you may not require.

As for removing Adobe Files, one can't really suggest if a file may be important or not and you may have to judge this for yourself. If you really have the time, a crude way to increase space would be to 1) uninstall all the Abobe software on your system 2) delete all Adobe software related files and folders then 3) install back all the Adobe software.

Answer (score 1):

Anything an application installs isn't *safe* to remove and still expect that the application will work fine. If you're running out of space, you should either look at your documents, or uninstall some applications that you're not using.